# How can I monitor website hits in heroku application?

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a developed web application in react.js and deployed on heroku platform. I would like to track no of hits to my website. How can I do that in Heroku?

I would like to achieve similar functionality to google analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the tool you're looking for is [react-ga](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga).  As per the documentation:

```
npm i react-ga
```

Then include the following in your App.js

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('<tracking_id>');  // Insert tracking_id from Google Analytics here
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

Note: By default Google will give you a tracking ID beginning with 'G-...' but this react package requires a tracking ID beginning with 'UA-...'  This [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-setup-and-add-google-analytics-to-your-react-app-fd361f47ac7b) explains how to get a tracking ID beginning with 'UA-...'

Comment: Thanks for the react-ga. Do I need to deploy app on google cloud platform in order to use google analytics?

Comment: @AmbarDudhane No you don't.  I have deployed my app on Heroku, but the google analytics works fine.  You can equally use AWS or Microsoft Azure for deployment - the google analytics will work regardless.

Comment: I have implemented react-ga in my app but I can only see active users in google analytics. Why cant I see past user activity?

Answer (score 2):

You can track your website hits using google analytics. All you need to create is google analytics account and get the tracking id. Once you get the tracking id add below code under  of your public/index.html replacing TRACKING_ID with you tracking id from google analytics.

```
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=<TRACKING-ID>"></script>
 <script>
 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
 function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
 gtag('js', new Date());

 gtag('config', '<TRACKING-ID>');

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any tool provided by heroku?

Comment: I am quite sure about that. I think they don't